# Selecting by multiIndex

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two DataFrames

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A1', 'B1', 'C1']], columns=['first', 'secound', 'third'])
df_a.set_index(['first', 'secound'], inplace=True)

df_b = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 'B', 12], ['A', 'B', 143], ['C1', 'C1', 11]], columns=['first', 'secound', 'data'])
df_b.set_index(['first', 'secound'], inplace=True)

              third
first secound      
A     B           C
A1    B1         C1

               data
first secound      
A     B          12
      B         143
C1    C1         11
```

How I can select only shared index elements in df_b:

```
               data
first secound      
A     B          12
      B         143
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take the intersection of the indexes, and use that as an indexer for `df_b.loc`:

```
In [28]: df_b.loc[df_b.index.intersection(df_a.index)]
Out[28]: 
               data
first secound      
A     B          12
      B         143
```

or, alternatively, use `isin` to generate a boolean mask for `df_b.loc`:

```
In [32]: df_b.loc[df_b.index.isin(df_a.index)]
Out[32]: 
               data
first secound      
A     B          12
      B         143
```

---

Using `isin` seems to be the fastest option:

### [image]

This was the setup used to generate the [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) above:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import perfplot


def isin(x):
    df_a, df_b = x
    return df_b.loc[df_b.index.isin(df_a.index)]

def intersection(x):
    df_a, df_b = x
    return df_b.loc[df_b.index.intersection(df_a.index)]

def join(x):
    df_a, df_b = x
    return df_a.drop(df_a.columns, axis=1).join(df_b).dropna()

def make_df(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(n, 3)))
    df = df.set_index([0, 1])
    return df

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: [make_df(n) for i in range(2)],
    kernels=[isin, intersection, join],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(2, 15)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=False,  # rows may appear in different order
    xlabel='len(df)')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could join the index of `df_a` with `df_b`, and then drop `NaN`s:

```
>>> df_a.drop(df_a.columns, axis=1).join(df_b).dropna()
                data
first secound       
A     B         12.0
      B        143.0
```