# combine DataFrame MultiIndex to string column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [11,22,33]], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
df.set_index(['A', 'B'], inplace=True)

        C
A  B     
1  2    3
11 22  33
```

How I make additional 'text' column that will be string combination of the MultiIndex.

Without removing my index!

For example:

```
        C    D
A  B            
1  2    3    1_2
11 22  33  11_22
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a simple list comprehension might help i.e

```
df['new'] = ['_'.join(map(str,i)) for i in df.index.tolist()]

        C    new
A  B            
1  2    3    1_2
11 22  33  11_22
```

Answer (score 3):

With so many elegant methods it is not clear which one to choose. So, here is a performance comparison of the methods provided in the other answers plus an alternative one for two cases: 1) the multi-index is comprised of integers; 2) the multi-index is comprised of strings.

Jezrael's method (f_3) wins in both cases. However, Dark's (f_2) is the slowest one for the second case. Method 1 performs very poorly with integers due to the type conversion step but is as fast as f_3 with strings.

Case 1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': randint(1, 10, num_rows), 'B': randint(10, 20, num_rows), 'C': randint(20, 30, num_rows)})
df.set_index(['A', 'B'], inplace=True)

# Method 1
def f_1(df): 
    df['D'] = df.index.get_level_values(0).astype('str') + '_' + df.index.get_level_values(1).astype('str')
    return df

## Method 2
def f_2(df):
    df['D'] = ['_'.join(map(str,i)) for i in df.index.tolist()]
    return df

## Method 3
def f_3(df): 
    df['D'] = [f'{i}_{j}' for i, j in df.index]
    return df

## Method 4
def f_4(df): 
    df['new'] = df.index.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
    return df
```

[image]

Case 2:

```
alpha = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice(alpha, size=num_rows), \
                     'B': np.random.choice(alpha, size=num_rows), \
                     'C': randint(20, 30, num_rows)})
df.set_index(['A', 'B'], inplace=True)

# Method 1
def f_1(df): 
    df['D'] = df.index.get_level_values(0) + '_' + df.index.get_level_values(1)
    return df
```

[image]

Comment: If there are 5 to 6 levels of index then??

Comment: @KRKirov - And what about graphs like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50318954/2901002) ? People love them... :)?

Comment: @jezrael I have added a graphical comparison for data frames with sizes between 0.5 to 30M rows.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df['new'] = df.index.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
```

Output:

```
        C    new
A  B            
1  2    3    1_2
11 22  33  11_22
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution in `python 3.6`:

```
df['new'] = [f'{i}_{j}' for i, j in df.index]
print (df)
        C    new
A  B            
1  2    3    1_2
11 22  33  11_22
```

And bellow:

```
df['new'] = ['{}_{}'.format(i,j) for i, j in df.index]
```

Comment: I thought the same but I doubt there will be only 2 levels. There might be more levels too na?

Comment: @Dark - I think generally it is no problem, because more as 4 levels `MultiIndex` are rarest used. And mainly 2 levels :)